# Why does this `range` implementation crash tabs in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I wrote this range function:

```
function range(m,n) {
    var x = m
    var xs = [x]
    var op = (m <= n) 
            ? function (a,b) { return a+b }
            : function (a,b) { return a-b }

    while (x !== n) {
        var x = op(x)
        xs.push(x)
    }
    return xs
 }
```

... but when called it crashes the tab in Chrome (linux 46.0.2490.86 (Official Build) (64-bit))

It gives the "aw, snap!" message, as well as "Inspected Target Disconnected", but nothing more specific.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your `op` function takes two arguments, yet you always give one. `op` will always return `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

You need different functions for counting

```js
function range(m, n) {
    var x = m,
        xs = [x],
        op = m <= n ? function (a) { return a + 1; } : function (a) { return a - 1; };

    while (x !== n) {
        x = op(x);
        xs.push(x);                
    }
    return xs;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(range(3, 11), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(range(7, 2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(range(42, 42), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: whoooops, totally my fault. Thanks!